# Flutter ChromeSafariBrowser not launching when device has a default browser other than Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm using [ChromeSafariBrowser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#chromesafaribrowser-class) in my app. I have a problem when running the app on an Android device which has a browser other than Chrome set as the default browser. In this case, the ChromeSafariBrowser is not running and InAppBrowser is launched with the device's default browser.
What should I do to fix this problem?

I want to launch with chrome, even if the user sets another default browser.

```java
    final ChromeSafariBrowser browser =
        new ChromeSafariBrowser(new InAppBrowser());


        await browser.open(
            url: loginUrl,
            options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
                android:
                AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,
                    packageName: "com.android.chrome"),
                ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use webviewflutter

In pubspec.yml file add dependency:

```
webview_flutter: ^0.1.1
```

For ioS App below keys paste in .plist file inside the ios project folder

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key><string>yes</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

and this is class code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class WebViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewClassState createState() => _WebViewClassState();
}

class _WebViewClassState extends State<WebViewClass> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use google sign in my web page. with web view, google do not allow to login with other browsers, except chrome.

Comment: As per the question, the URL should get open on Google Chrome browser only not on any another browser. How does this help this, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the problem myself and found out that the problem was already fixed by `InAppWebView` team. If you need more detailed information please see [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/391).